# AngularJS How to include a directive inside a template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write a reusable component using directives in AngularJS. The problem I'm having is that inside my reusable component, in the template, I want to use *another* directive.  However, this directive has a `require` attribute and it throws an error as if it fails the requirement even if it shouldn't.  [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UTZCj7ryuNRxKONnYfVR?p=preview) is a plunker.

#### Error

> Controller 'div', required by directive 'inner', can't be found!

#### Directives

```
  directive('inner', function(){
    return {
      require: 'div',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs){
        console.log('Inner Link');
      }
    }
  }).
  directive('outer', function($timeout){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      link:  function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){
        console.log('Outer Link')
      }
    }
  })
```

#### Template

```
<div>
  <div inner></div>
</div>
```

### Edit

Instead of `div` for the inner element and require, it should be `input`.

Comment: what is `div` supposed to be in your `require` ? It might be worthwhile explaining your full objective

Comment: As I commented below, it's actually supposed to be an `input`.  I'm trying to do reusable form controls.

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes.

1. `require` takes the required directive name, not the element you attached it
   to.
2. `outer` needs a controller, because that's what `inner` needs.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1epiLV1zjAlXlOodrkO3?p=preview

```
    angular.module('plunker', []).
      directive('inner', function(){
        return {
          require: '^outer',
          link: function (scope, elem, attrs){
            console.log('Inner Link');
          }
        }
      }).
      directive('outer', function($timeout){
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: 'template.html',
          link:  function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){
            console.log('Outer Link')
          },
          controller: function() {

          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Yeah sorry for the require.  In my code I actually use `input`.  The important part is that it doesn't seem to recognise the directive (in this case, input) inside the template.

Comment: it does. check the console of the plunker

Comment: does it?[new plunker with input](http://plnkr.co/edit/eXhBbU1OglcpCtVYnNSR?p=preview)

Comment: @circuitlego You're once again putting an element in `require`. put `outer` instead. Did you even read the answer?

Comment: @circuitlego Is your intention to actually limit the directive to a specific element, or are you just trying to make it work inside `outer`'s tepmlate

Comment: Yes, I did read your answer.  My intention is that it only works on inputs.  Also, as per the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input), input *is* a directive, just like form.

Comment: It also has no controller, which is what `require` is expecting to find. Perhaps you can limit by checking element.localName in the link instead.

Comment: Oooooh OK.  That makes more sense now.  Thanks ;)

Comment: Cool :) I can't really think of any other way of accomplishing that. Perhaps people smarter than me have a better suggestion now that you know better what you're looking for